# jQuery menu using <a> tags

Tags: jquery, menu, web, lnk

I'm making a very basic menu but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using jQuery for it. Here's what I have so far.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#lnk").click(function(){
        top.location.href="http://"+this.lnk
    });
});
</script>
```

I've used a custom "lnk" attribute to store the site link. Can anyone help?

Comment: I see you are setting the href attribute of something,  but not actually doing anything else, try sending the click event to the element you've set the href of ,  assuming it's an <a></a> element????

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do,  but you'll need to explain what 'top.location' is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
$("a#lnk").click(function(){
  top.location.href="http://"+$(this).attr('lnk');
});
```

but this makes no sense to me, because it's already a link and you shuold use the href attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you must store custom data like that, use the data attribute: `data-lnk="foo.com"` rather than making a bogus attribute up, but why not just use the href?

```
<a class="lnk" href="http://foo.com">my link</a>


$("a.lnk").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   top.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, why not just use href? For whatever reason you prefer not to, as mentioned above I would use the html5 data attribute.

As of jQuery 1.4.3 up any data- attribute will automatically be pulled into the jQuery data object. I would suggest using this over .attr to access the value.